# Dotnet Core on AWS Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: json, .net-core

I'm new on AWS Lambda using Dotnet Core. I created new project template using AWS Lambda Project (.NET Core) on Visual Studio. And the function HelloWorld is very basic which return the UpperCase only

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            return input?.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

Created successfully and published to AWS successfully. But I cannot invoke in Postman... I get below message

```
[
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)",
    "at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
]
```

I run the test using AWSToolkitPackage on Visual Studio, it work! Because the input parameter is a string. But on PostMan, I tried to put a string as well but it did not work... Does anyone have experience on this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you post all of your code in your lambda?

Comment: hello, I updated the full code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this line

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization;
```

Without that line, this line

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
```

doesn't really work

Comment: it doesn't work... I tested with VS, it works, but with PostMan, it doesn't. I think because in VS they allow to input the param as "string", but PostMan pass the param as "json", I think...

Answer (score 1):

Ah!!!! I found a solution. Instead of using "string", use "JObject" instead